# Phosphoric acid before galvanic coating?

Tags: steel, rust-proofing

I want to protect some mild steel. I have removed all the rust with a flap disk but there are some pits left in the steel. I have tried to remove thse using electrolysis and now with to paint this.

Do I first coat with phosporic acid (etching) then apply the cold zinc galvanic spray, or do I do this the other way around, or do I need to apply the etching at all?

Comment: You can't remove pits, they are holes in the steel.   The gold standard for surface prep is media blasting, search your area for "maker spaces" that will let you use their sand blaster.  Anyway if you're the kind of person who drops metal in phosphoric acid, maker spaces are something you might want to be more involved in.

Comment: I thought phosphoric acid was a standard method of cleaning rust or at least converting adhering loose rust to immobile iron phosphate which can be primed and then painted.